# Работа плагина после ajax подгрузки модального окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Загрузка модального окна происходит так:

```
getModalHtml(window.location.origin + '/workspace/show');
$('#modal-block').modal("show");
```

`getModalHtml` - принимает `url`, отправляет по нему запрос, и вставляет в модальное окно принятый `html`. Так же используется `bootstrap-select`:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="5">
    <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
    <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

При загрузке он не работал. После того как я добавил в `bootstrap-select.js`:

```
$(document).on("shown.bs.modal", "#modal-block", function() {
    $('#modal-block .selectpicker').each(function() {
        var $selectpicker = $(this);
        Plugin.call($selectpicker, $selectpicker.data());
    })
});
```

Оно срабатывает, но с неплохой задержкой, а иногда и вовсе не срабатывает.

Есть ли универсальное решение такой проблемы? Подобная проблема возникает и другими плагинами.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/3300qmoj/1/

Все сводится к паре строк кода

```
  var $modal = $(responseHTML).modal({show:false});
  $modal.find('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
  $('body').append(modal);
  $modal.modal('show');
```

Comment: Попробовал такой вариант, все работает. Но как мне получить доступ к модали? У меня ее id modal-block, но $('#modal-block').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {}); не работает, как и другие попытки по id обратиться

Comment: Зачем обращаться к нему по id, когда модальное окно находится в переменной  $modal, код выходит id независимый.
Обновил jsFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/3300qmoj/4/.